# Own post on own website

Tags: discussion, questions

I am planning to update my website. I would like to show all my posts in Stack Overflow in my webpage by using the Stack Overflow API, is that allowed?

**Note:** it is not about promoting my website in Stack Overflow, but actually promoting Stack Overflow in my website.

Comment: Note that duplicating content *may* mean you get hit by Google's duplicate content penalty. I'm not entirely sure how this works, by the way, I just know it exists :-) It may be something to look in to if you care about it.

Comment: There's a Wordpress plugin for that if you use WP

Comment: @Hack-R Just curious, what's the plugin called, I can't seem to find one?

Comment: @luweiqi It looks like the ones I use on http://hack-r.com that I was thinking of are StackOverflow Answers Widget and StackOverflow+ (mostly the former, though the latter is good too and I didn't remember until now that they were 2 separate plugins).

Comment: @Hack-R have you have any issues regarding google duplicate content? as Carpetsmoker mentions if so what was your strategy to solve it. Some other mentions terms and conditions of api is there any remarkable thing to mention form your experience so far?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I haven't noticed anything. I don't watch my blog or its rankings very closely, but it's really more of just links to SO with descriptions, so I don't think it's truely duplicate content anyway. Sometimes I've posted a tutorial to my blog and used parts of it to answer SO questions and that seems to have actually gotten more views on both the blog and the SO question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your original material is still yours. You can do whatever you want with it. It's not owned by Stack Overflow; you've just licensed it to them to publish. (See [Terms of Service, section 3 "Subscriber Content"](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service).) (They, in turn, offer it for relicensing to *other* people, but that doesn't mean that you're using *your own work* under that license.)

If you wanted to use the Stack Overflow logo or name on your site, that would be covered by their [Trademark Guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Comment: That what I wanted to ensure,

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ IANAL but I would think that you would still be subject to the Terms and Conditions of API usage (since you are using that to get the data). I can't imagine how you would possibly be violating that, but its something to keep in mind.

Comment: If you fetch some of your own posts edited by others, you'll probably have to reference Stack Overflow and give credits anyway, since you share other's work. Same applies to answers on your questions and questions you answered.

Comment: To be precise, using the Stack Exchange name would be _nominative use_ ; which is covered by trademark law. IOW, even if Stack Exchange  Inc. would change their guidance, such nominative use would remain allowed.